# Validate form on submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

I have created five input fields and a submit button to validate that fields but somehow it is not validated on submit.
In my JS I print the error dynamically. I have debugged by code and I get the proper values and errors, but it doesn't displays dynamically.

```js
function seterror(id, error) {
  // set error
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  debugger;
  console.log(element);
  element.getElementsByClassName('ferror')[0].innerHTML = error;
}

function validateForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var returnval = true;

  var name = document.forms['myForm']['fname'].value;
  if (name.length < 5) {
    seterror("uname", "abc");
    returnval = false;
  }

  return returnval;
}
```

```css
.ferror {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Form Validation Demo</h1>
<form onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="myForm">

  Name*: <input type="text" id="uname" name="fname"><b><span class="ferror"></span></b><br> Password*: <input type="password" id="pass" name="fpass"><b><span class="ferror"></span></b><br> Confirm Password*: <input type="password" id="cpassword" name="fcpass"><b><span class="ferror"></span></b>  <br> Email*: <input type="email" id="uemail" name="femail"><b><span class="ferror"></span></b> <br> Phone*:
  <input type="phone" id="uphone" name="fphone"><b><span class="ferror"></span></b> <br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="submit">

</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *"i have tried validation on form but somehow it's not validate form?"* A question title is expected to describe in the shortest possible way a question to a specific issue.

Comment: Avoid the use of `on*` attributes. JS should be in one place only. It's tag, or respective file. Use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead

Comment: Also, either use `<script defer src=""></script>` (if in head) or simply place your script tags right **before the closing** `</body>` tag

Comment: `name.length < 5` is better written as `name.length <= 4` - less cognitive load and more explicitly presents the desired `4`

Comment: @Rocko C. Buljan i have made all suggested changes still getting same error

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` will inevitably prevent the form submission. You should place `e.preventDefault();` in the statement where you have eventual errors - at the end of your validation function. `if (errorsExits) e.preventDefault(); // don't submit form`

Comment: Actually you're not passing the event object, there should be an error message in the console. The event object is present only in the inline code, it's not magically passed to `validateForm` function when it's called like `validateForm()`. You can use the global event object instead of `e`, i.e. `event.preventDefault();`, or pass `event` from the inline code. But as Roko already said, attaching event listeners with a proper method would fix the code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given all the comments under the question, here's my suggestion for a more flexible remake:

- Don't use IDs for your fields
- Use an additional `<label>` as wrapper
- Don't bloat HTML with useless empty `<span>` error elements - create them using JS
- Use a proper [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and use its Event in the Validation function
- Use an `errors` array to store all the errors during each part of the validation
- Only at the end, if the `errors` Array has items in it (meaning something is invalid) - in that case use `Event.preventDefault()` to prevent the form being submitted.

```js
// Utility functions:
const EL = (sel, parent) => (parent || document).querySelector(sel);
const ELS = (sel, parent) => (parent || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const ELNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);


// Form validation script:
const EL_form = EL("#myForm");

const validateForm = (evt) => {

  // Remove old errors
  ELS(".ferror", EL_form).forEach(el => el.remove());

  // Prepare an array to hold your errors
  const errors = [];

  // Get the desired fields:
  
  const EL_fname = EL('[name="fname"]', EL_form);
  const EL_fpass = EL('[name="fpass"]', EL_form);
  const EL_fcpass = EL('[name="fcpass"]', EL_form);
  const EL_femail = EL('[name="femail"]', EL_form);
  const EL_fphone = EL('[name="fphone"]', EL_form);

  // Validation and errors:
  
  if (EL_fname.value.trim().length <= 4) {
    errors.push({name: "fname", text: "Name is too short (min 4 chars)"});
  }
  
  if (EL_fpass.value.trim().length <= 8) {
    errors.push({name: "fpass", text: "Password is too short (min 8 chars)"});
  }
  
  if (EL_fpass.value !== EL_fcpass.value) {
    errors.push({name: "fcpass", text: "Passwords do not match"});
  }
  
  if (!/^.+@.+\./.test(EL_femail.value)) {
    errors.push({name: "femail", text: "Invalid Email address"});
  }
  
  if (EL_fphone.value.trim().replace(/\D/g, "").length <= 6) {
    errors.push({name: "fphone", text: "Invalid telephone number"});
  }
  
  // Show errors:
  errors.forEach(err => {
    const EL_error = ELNew("span", {
      className: "ferror",
      textContent: err.text,
    });
    EL(`[name="${err.name}"]`, EL_form).closest("label").append(EL_error);
  });
  
  // Prevent Form subnit on any error
  if (errors.length) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
  
};

EL_form.addEventListener("submit", validateForm);
```

```css
form label {
  display: block;
}
.ferror {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">

  <label>Name: <input name="fname" type="text"></label>
  <label>Password: <input name="fpass" type="password"></label>
  <label>Confirm Password: <input name="fcpass" type="password"></label>
  <label>Email: <input name="femail" type="email"></label>
  <label>Phone: <input name="fphone" type="phone"></label>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit">
  
</form>
```